# Matching whole words only for Greek

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to match a whole polytonic Greek word via the Replace Text extension in MW 1.31 (server running MariaDB 10.3.22).

When I want to match a whole word (one word only) in ASCII characters I use something like

```
Example Text: <b class="b2">suspicion</b>
Find: <b class="b2">([\w]+)<\/b>
Replace: [[$1]]
```

Or for two words:

```
Example Text: <b class="b2">suspicion, feeling</b>
Find: <b class="b2">([\w]+), (([\w]+)<\/b>
Replace: [[$1]], [[$2]]
```

But with Greek words word boundaries to not work. I tried:

```
Example Text 1: <b class="b2">λογισμὸς, ἑστὼς, καὶ νουνεχής</b>
Example Text 2: <b class="b2">λογισμὸς</b>

<b class="b2">(.*?[Α-Ωα-ωίϊίΐἶἶἴῖἰἱἵἰὶἱἸόὀὁόὅὍὄάἄἅᾳἀἁᾴὰάᾷέέἐἑἕἕἔύϋύΰὖῦῆἠἡἥἦἤἤἩῃήήῇώῳώῶῷὠὦὧὠᾠὤὥὡπῥσὑὐὕφΧψ]+?.*?)<\/b>
```

But this matches more than one word, i.e. it will match both the first example and the second.

Comment: To match whole Greek words, you may use `/\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b/u`, see https://regex101.com/r/gLTLA6/2

Comment: That does not match anything in my case (Maria DB 10.3 via Mediawiki Replace Extension)

Comment: It is because you need to use a pattern, not the delimiters. `(*UCP)\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b` or `(*UTF)(*UCP)\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b` should work

Comment: No pages were found containing the string "(*UCP)\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b".

Comment: The second `(*UTF)(*UCP)\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b` did find all words, but when trying to match a single word between tags like `<b class="b3">(*UTF)(*UCP)\b(?:(?=\p{Greek})\p{L})+\b<\/b>` I got Fatal exception of type "Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError"

Comment: Ok, I suspect all you want is actually `(*UTF16)(*UCP)<b class="b2">(\w+)</b>` or `(*UTF16)(*UCP)<b class="b2">(\w+), (\w+)</b>`. Or  `<b class="b2">(\p{L}+)</b>` or `<b class="b2">(\p{L}+), (\p{L}+)</b>`

Comment: Thanks, that gives "Fatal exception of type "Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError". Using (*UTF) instead of (*UTF16) gives no error, finds matching pages (although it does not display the matched text, as it does when replacements are known to work), so when replacing with [[$2]] nothing happens.

Comment: This appears to work for a single word in very few cases `<b class="b3">(\p{L}+)<\/b>` (needed an escape before the closing tag slash) missing though most matches, like for example, `inf. <b class="b3">καμεῖν</b>, Ep. `

Comment: This appears to work, needed the escape again `(*UTF)(*UCP)<b class="b3">(\w+)<\/b>`

Answer (score 0):

You may enable Unicode awareness for the `\w` char by using `(*UTF)(*UCP)` PCRE verb sequence at the start of the pattern:

```
(*UTF)(*UCP)<b class="b3">(\w+)<\/b>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLTLA6/4).

As per the [PCRE documentation](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html):

> The original operation of PCRE was on strings of one-byte characters. However, there is now also support for UTF-8 strings in the original library, an extra library that supports 16-bit and UTF-16 character strings, and a third library that supports 32-bit and UTF-32 character strings. To use these features, PCRE must be built to include appropriate support. When using UTF strings you must either call the compiling function with the `PCRE_UTF8`, `PCRE_UTF16`, or `PCRE_UTF32` option, or the pattern must start with one of these special sequences:
>
> `(*UTF8)`
> `(*UTF16)`
> `(*UTF32)`
> `(*UTF)`
>
> `(*UTF)` is a generic sequence that can be used with any of the libraries. Starting a pattern with such a sequence is equivalent to setting the relevant option.
>
> Another special sequence that may appear at the start of a pattern is `(*UCP)`. This has the same effect as setting the PCRE_UCP option: it causes sequences such as `\d` and `\w` to use Unicode properties to determine character types, instead of recognizing only characters with codes less than 128 via a lookup table.